# Guava: synchronize few LoadingCaches among one another

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

***I've got:*** Web application based on websockets (non-blocking io). Each users tab in browser is associated with a `Peer` object. Also there are three global peer collections, accessible from each `Peer` through `peer.engine.*Peers` reference chain. See code below:

```
public class Peer implements WebSocketListener {
   private org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session session;
   private long sessionId;
   private Engine engine;

   public Peer(Engine engine) {
       this.engine = engine;
   }

   //all WebSocketListener methods implementation
}

//singleton
public class Engine {
   // Where key is the peer.sessionId 
   //HERE IS THE POINT: each user can remove, add, replace elements of caches with the same key (`sessionId`) in concurrent way.
   LoadingCache<Long, Peer> activePeers; 
   LoadingCache<Long, Peer> inactivePeers; 
   LoadingCache<Long, Peer> closedPeers; 

   private Engine(LoadingCache<Long, Peer> a, LoadingCache<Long, Peer> b, LoadingCache<Long, Peer> c) {
      this.activePeers = a;
      this.inactivePeers = b;
      this.closedPeers = c;
   }
}
```

***Problem explanation:*** Each peer can *add*, *remove* himself or other peers from all *Peers collections, or *replace* other peers from one collection to another. **PROBLEM:** There are many peers, all happens **concurrently**.

***Important nuance!:*** If user  works with my application from many tabs - he'll have many peers. User can *touch* (means add, remove, replace) only his peers. I mean each peer can *touch* (add, remove, replace) only peers that have THE SAME key in the `LoadingCache`.

***QUESTION:*** Do I need to synchronize all those operations (add, remove, replace) or *LoadingCache* has already done it for me?

***P.S.*** If you need extra explanation - just ask, you are welcome!

Comment: Uh, why not embed the peer state in the `Peer` class? You'd then only have one cache to deal with. Also, how is your cache built? Do you have a `RemovalListener` set up?

Comment: What do you mean by replace/remove/add, are you getting the map from the cache by calling AsMap? Or do you refer to the "invalidate" method?

Comment: @fge 2) yes I have a `RemovalListener` which in some cases just move `Peer` to another collection. For example, if access_timeout happens, I move peer from `activePeers` to `inactivePeers` in `RemovalListener`. 1) What do you mean by Peer state. Those collections contains all peers of all users. I have to store them in one place to allow communication between users

Comment: @Chunkz Example: I have `peer1` in `inactivePeers` map. On some event I should replace `peer1` and all existing peers for which true `peer.sessionId == peer1.sessionId` to `activePeers` cache. Can I achieve that with `invalidate`? If yes, than there is no matter either to use `asMap` or `invalidate`.

Comment: Can a peer have more than one state? ie can they be closed AND active at the same time? Otherwise I would agree with @fge that a attribute that indicates their current state should create cleaner and less error prone code.

Comment: @Volodymyr, What do you mean with "replace all existing peers"? If the sessionId is the key then there can only be one.

Comment: One thing I fail to understand here: why do you need a `LoadingCache` at all? Can't a `Cache` be enough? Also, why pass them as constructor arguments and not create them when you initialize the instance instead?

Comment: @Chunkz why only the one. At least in `HashMap`  there can be a lot baskets (entities) with the same key. In my case each user tab associated with different peers, but all user's peers have the same `sessionId`

Comment: @fge 2) pass arguments only for demo. In my project I initialize them right away the Engine is creating. 1) I need map which will automatically remove entities on access/write timeout. Is `Cache` appropriate in my case?

Comment: Well yes, you can add a `RemovalListener` to a `Cache`; just `.build()` without a `CacheLoader` and you get a `Cache` instead of a `LoadingCache` (you do use `CacheBuilder` to build, right?)

Comment: @fge yes. But still, explain me if I need some synchronization during operations with `Cache`?

Comment: Yes you will; a cache is synchronized by itself, but it is unaware of others. What bugs me more though is the definition of a peer itself and its lifecycle: I am sure there is a way to not have to use three caches.

Comment: @fge actually the problem is that due `WebsocketListener` lifecycle doesn't allow to make it more simple in my situation. Can you provide me an exception (race) scenarios and I'll consider if they are possible in my case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this API :/

Comment: @fge I didn't mean websockets =) I just mean mean scenarios when replacing/adding/removing is dangereous in code sample above. Because I can't imagine that